# How to clear Knetwalk scores?

Tags: games

I would like to clear Knetwalk high scores.

No such info in the manual.

Please tell me if you know

Comment: @David It is not spam as defined by this site. It is not an attempt to promote a product or service. In my opinion, this question is a legitimate request for assistance with a known Ubuntu application. If you disagree, I recommend that you raise a question at Meta. https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions

Comment: @David -- Yes, we answer questions about software that runs on Ubuntu, especially software in official repositories like this one.

Comment: Two links of interest here: 
1. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=knetwalk&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all
2. https://askubuntu.com/conduct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the terminal:

```
rm ~/.config/knetwalkrc
```

All scores, difficulty settings, etc. will be erased. When you start a new game, the file will be recreated with default settings.